# Woocommerce stripe Credit card input field appear then suddenly disappears after page is loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

**Edit**

What I have noticed is if stripe input element is outside of this div element
`div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment"`
(this is located in payment.php)
then it renders without disappearing but if it's inside of it then it disappears. So i'm assume woocommerce is affecting this.

---

When page is not fully loaded yet the stripe card input element appears, but when page is fully loaded it suddenly disappears.

Sometimes I get this error message - 'controller-cc848a9ad…2497a003323d67.js:1 [Stripe.js] The selector you specified (#stripe-card-element) applies to 2 DOM elements that are currently on the page. The Stripe Element will be mounted to the first one.'

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Stripe-PHP-integration
 * Description: PHP API Integration For Wordpress
 * Author: Null
 * Version: 1.0
**/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

require_once 'stripe/init.php';

use Stripe\Stripe;

add_action('init', function() {

    Stripe::setApiKey('');
    Stripe::setClientId('');

});

header('Content-Type: application/json');



add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_gateway_class');
function init_custom_gateway_class(){

    class WC_Gateway_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {


        /**
         * Constructor for the gateway.
         */
        public function __construct() {

            $this->id                 = 'Stripe-Payment';
            $this->icon               = apply_filters('woocommerce_custom_gateway_icon', '');
            $this->has_fields         = false;
            $this->method_title       = __( 'Stripe PHP API Integration For WooCommerce', $this->domain );
            $this->method_description = __( 'Allows payments using Stripe PHP API', $this->domain );

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();


            // Define user set variables
            $this->title        = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );
            $this->order_status = $this->get_option( 'order_status', 'pending' );
            

            // Actions
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );

            // Customer Emails
            add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );
            add_action('woocommerce_payment_fields', array($this, 'payment_fields'));
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
            add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'include_stripe_js'));

            


        }
        
        
        public function enqueue_styles() {
            wp_enqueue_style('stripe-custom-styles', 'https://getvagu.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/css/stripe-styles.css?ver=7.7.0');
        }
        
        public function include_stripe_js() {
                ?>
                <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
                <script>
                    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');
                    
                    const options = {
                    mode: 'payment',
                    amount: 1099,
                    currency: 'usd',
                      appearance: {/*...*/},
                    };
                    
                    const elements = stripe.elements(options);

                    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
                   
                    paymentElement.mount('#stripe_payment_form');

                </script>
                <?php
        }
        
                

        /**
         * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
         */
        public function init_form_fields() {

            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', $this->domain ),
                    'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    'label'   => __( 'Enable Custom Payment', $this->domain ),
                    'default' => 'yes'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Title', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => __( 'Stripe PHP API', $this->domain ),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'order_status' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Order Status', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'select',
                    'class'       => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                    'description' => __( 'Choose whether status you wish after checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => 'wc-completed',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'options'     => wc_get_order_statuses()
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Description', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => __('Payment Information', $this->domain),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'instructions' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Instructions', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Instructions that will be added to the thank you page and emails.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => '',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
            );
        }
        
        
        

        /**
         * Output for the order received page.
         */
        public function thankyou_page() {
            if ( $this->instructions )
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) );
        }

        /**
         * Add content to the WC emails.
         *
         * @access public
         * @param WC_Order $order
         * @param bool $sent_to_admin
         * @param bool $plain_text
         */
        public function email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text = false ) {
            if ( $this->instructions && ! $sent_to_admin && $order->payment_method && $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) ) . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        
        
        

        /**
         * Renders the Stripe elements form.
         *
         */
        public function payment_fields(){
            ?>
                  <div id="stripe_payment_form"></div>
            <?php
        }

        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result.
         *
         * @param int $order_id
         * @return array
         */
        public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );


            $payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => $order->get_total() * 100,
                'currency' => strtolower(get_woocommerce_currency()),
                'payment_method' => $order->get_payment_method(),
                'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
                'confirm' => true,
                'return_url' => $this->get_return_url($order),
            ]);

            // Set order status
            $order->update_status('pending', __('Waiting for payment confirmation', $this->domain));

            // or call the Payment complete
            // $order->payment_complete();


            // Remove cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            // Return thankyou redirect
            return array(
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => $payment_intent->client_secret,
            );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'Stripe_PHP_API_Woocommerce_Integration' );
function Stripe_PHP_API_Woocommerce_Integration( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Custom'; 
    return $methods;
}



?>
```

Here's payment.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout Payment Section
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/payment.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 8.1.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment' );
}
?>

<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">
    <div class="form-row place-order">
        <noscript>
            <?php
            /* translators: $1 and $2 opening and closing emphasis tags respectively */
            printf( esc_html__( 'Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the %1$sUpdate Totals%2$s button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.', 'woocommerce' ), '<em>', '</em>' );
            ?>
            <br/><button type="submit" class="button alt<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        </noscript>

        <?php //wc_get_template( 'checkout/terms.php' ); ?>

    </div>
    

    
    <h3 class="mt-2 mb-4 has-text-weight-bold is-flex is-align-items-center">
        <span class="icon is-small mr-2">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/sleep/images/card-ic1.svg" alt="" />
            <!--<i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i>-->
        </span>
        Step 3: Payment Methods
    </h3>

    <div class="payment-method-cc new-pay">
        <h5 class="tit-add">Credit card  <img src="/wp-content/themes/sleep/images/all-card1.svg" alt=""></h5>
        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) : ?>

            <ul class="wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods">
                <?php
                if ( ! empty( $available_gateways ) ) {
                    foreach ( $available_gateways as $gateway ) {
                        wc_get_template( 'checkout/payment-method.php', array( 'gateway' => $gateway ) );
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<li>';
                    wc_print_notice( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_no_available_payment_methods_message', WC()->customer->get_billing_country() ? esc_html__( 'Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make alternate arrangements.', 'woocommerce' ) : esc_html__( 'Please fill in your details above to see available payment methods.', 'woocommerce' ) ), 'notice' ); // phpcs:ignore WooCommerce.Commenting.CommentHooks.MissingHookComment
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        

        
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit' ); ?>
        
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center mt-2">
                <label class="check-new">
                   <strong> I confirm that I have read and agree to <a href="https://getvagu.com/terms-conditions/" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="https://getvagu.com/privacy-policy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>.</strong>
        
                    <input type="checkbox" class="mr-2 agree-checkbox" id="terms-of-service" name="terms-of-service" required="" />
                    <span class="checkmark mb-0" for="terms-of-service"></span>
                </label>
            </div>

        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt is-size-5 p-3 my-3 btn-pay paynow' . esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ) . '" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" style="font-weight: 700; background: #00c349 !important;">Order Now</button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit' ); ?>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-process_checkout', 'woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_payment' );
}
```

And here's payment-method.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Output a single payment method
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/payment-method.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version     3.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>">
    <input id="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( $gateway->chosen, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" />

    <label for="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>">
        <?php echo $gateway->get_title(); /* phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped */ ?> <?php echo $gateway->get_icon(); /* phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped */ ?>
    </label>
    <?php if ( $gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description() ) : ?>
        <div class="payment_box payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php if ( ! $gateway->chosen ) : /* phpcs:ignore Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.NewlineAfterOpenBrace */ ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; /* phpcs:ignore Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.NewlineAfterOpenBrace */ ?>>
            <?php $gateway->payment_fields(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

here's main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li#menu-item-215 > a").addClass("myBtn_policy");
    $("li#menu-item-215 > a").attr("data-title","Contact Us");
    $("li#menu-item-215 > a").attr("data-id",216);
    $("#menu-item-225 > a").addClass("myBtn_policy");
    $("#menu-item-225 > a").attr("data-title","Track order");
    $("#menu-item-225 > a").attr("data-id",223);
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var cl = document.getElementById("close");
    $(".myBtn_policy").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Popup_Title = $(this).attr("data-title");
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("Popup_Title").innerHTML = Popup_Title;
        $("#myModal #policy_content").html("");
        form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('action', 'ajax_post');
        form_data.append('id',id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data, 
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#myModal #policy_content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });

    
    $( "body" ).on( "click","#close", function() {
        $("#myModal").css("display","none");
        $("#myModal").removeClass("active")
    });

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            $("#myModal").removeClass("active");
        }
    };
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("card-header");

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
    if(document.querySelector("#billing_phone")){
        var input = document.querySelector("#billing_phone");
        window.intlTelInput(input, {           
             separateDialCode:true,
             initialCountry: "us",
        });
    }
    var one = 0;
    var ten = 0;
    var hundered = 6;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        time();
    }, 0.7);
    function time() {
        one--;
        if (one == -1) {
            ten = ten - 1;
            one = 0 + 9;
        }
        if (ten == -1) {
            hundered = hundered - 1;
            ten = 0 + 9;
        }
        var wholeNum = hundered + "" + ten + "" + one;
        if (wholeNum == 250) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        $(".timer").html("<span>" + hundered + "</span><span>" + ten + "</span><span>" + one + "</span>");
    }
    var spd = 100;
    var spdVal = 10;
    var cntDown = 7 * 60 * spdVal;
    setInterval(function () {
        var mn, sc, ms;
        cntDown--;
        if (cntDown < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        mn = Math.floor(cntDown / spdVal / 60);
        mn = mn < 10 ? "0" + mn : mn;
        sc = Math.floor((cntDown / spdVal) % 60);
        sc = sc < 10 ? "0" + sc : sc;
        ms = Math.floor(cntDown % spdVal);
        ms = ms < 10 ? "0" + ms : ms;
        var result = mn + ":" + sc;
        //  document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = result;
    }, spd);
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        breakpoints: {
            640: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            1024: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
            },
        },
    });
    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function () {
        return (
            window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function (callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            }
        );
    })();
    $(".slide-testimonial").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 15,
        dots: false,
        responsiveClass: true,
        navText: ['<img src="index_files/arw-left.svg"/>', '<img src="index_files/arw-right.svg"/>'],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: false,
                dots: true,
            },
            600: {
                items: 2,
                nav: false,
                dots: true,
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3,
                nav: false,
                dots: true,
            },
            1200: {
                items: 3,
                nav: true,
                dots: false,
            },
        },
    });

    $("select").before('<div class="select_arr"></div>');
    $("#nav-toggle").click(function () {
        $(".mobile-tog").slideToggle(700);

        $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden");
    });

    $(".mobile-tog a").click(function () {
        $(".mobile-tog").slideToggle(0);

        $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden");
    });
    $(".add_order, .option-quantity").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn = $(this),
        id = btn.attr('data-id'),
        order = btn.attr('data-order');
        form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('action', 'ajax_add');
        form_data.append('id',id);
        form_data.append('order',order);
        if(btn.hasClass("option-quantity")){
            $(".option-quantity").removeClass("is-active");
            btn.addClass("is-active");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data, 
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("form.checkout").append('<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.6; cursor: default; position: absolute;"></div>');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(".blockOverlay").remove();
                $(".update_checkout").click();
                if(btn.hasClass("add_order")){
                    window.location.href='/checkout/';
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var dheight = $(".banner-left").height();
        if (scroll >= dheight / 4) {
            $(".stickybtn").addClass("stickybtn_fixed");
        } else {
            $(".stickybtn").removeClass("stickybtn_fixed");
        }
    });




    //***** Fomo popup  *****//
    let obj = $("#fomo");
    let city = function () {
        return cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)];
    };
    let name = function () {
        return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    };
    let ago = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    };

    let putData = function () {
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 2;
        //console.log(number);
        let productimg = fomo_images + "product" + number + ".png";
        let productname = number + "x Vagu Stimulators";
        jQuery(".notification-container .notification-text .name").text(name);
        jQuery(".notification-container .notification-text .city").text(city);
        jQuery(".notification-container .notification-text .ago").text(ago);
        //jQuery(".notification-container .notification-text .productimg").attr('src', productimg);
        $(".productimg").attr("src", productimg);
        jQuery(".notification-container .notification-text .productname").text(productname);
    };
    let timer = 5000; //randomIntFromInterval(9000, 15000);
    //console.log(timer);
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
    function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions) {
        let x = 0;
        let intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
            callback();
            if (++x === repetitions) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        task(i);
    }
    timer = 5000;
    function task(i) {
        let interval = 8000;
        let stay = 6000;
        if (i > 0) {
            timer = interval + stay + timer;
        }

        //console.log(timer);
        setTimeout(function () {
            putData();
            $(obj).show("medium", function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(obj).hide("medium");
                }, stay); //Lenth time show //Display each notification for
            });
        }, timer);
    }

});
```

After page is loading/loaded the stripe input fields disappear.

Comment: Looking at the code you've shared, it appears that your `#stripe-card-element` node is conditionally rendered. I suspect that WooCommerce is also mounting an Element inside your `#wc-stripe-elements-field` node, but this block is not rendered because of your if condition. I'd first try deduplicating the Elements instances, and work from there.

Comment: It's weird, I revamped most of the code then tried implementing this
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
They're rendered but once page is loaded they disappear